# Android JSON doesnt parse on samsung gio

Tags: android, json

I've got a strange exception when trying to parse some JSON on samsung gio (running 2.3.6), I've tried it on xperia neo (running 4.0) it works well, also I've tried different JSON it works on both devices, I've validate JSON and it's valid! I provide code , json files , and logcat, help is appreciated.

parser

```
public static JSONObject getJSONObject(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException
{
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    inputStream = entity.getContent();
    //buildJSONString( inputStream );
    String s = buildJSONString( inputStream );
    Log.v("", s); // note that s is printed along all json files and all devices
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject( s );
    Log.v("", jObj +""); // it doesnt print on samsung, prints on xperia
    return jObj ;
} 
private static String buildJSONString( InputStream inputStream ) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=null;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"), 8);
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        if (inputStream != null)
            inputStream.close();
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

working json

```
{
    "song_list": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title_en": "Aces High",
            "artist_en": "IRON MAIDEN",
            "thumb_url": "http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/iron_maiden.jpg",
            "media_url": "http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/iron_maiden.mp3",
            "preview_url": "blabla",
            "num_download": "2846",
            "price": "0.50",
            "rating" : "4"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "title_en": "Wasted Years",
            "artist_en": "IRON MAIDEN",
            "thumb_url": "http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/iron_maiden.jpg",
            "media_url": "http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/iron_maiden.mp3",
            "preview_url": "blabla",
            "num_download": "1984",
            "price": "0.50",
            "rating" : "4"
        }
    ]
}
```

not working json

```
{
    "artist_list": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "artist_en": "MOTORHEAD",
            "artist_ar": "موتورهيد",
            "thumb_url": "http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/motorhead.jpg",
            "num_download": "2846"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "artist_en": "WHITESNAKE",
            "artist_ar": "وايتسنيك",
            "thumb_url": "http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/whitesnake.jpg",
            "num_download": "1984"
        }
    ]
}
```

serverhit

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
{
    try
    {   jObject = JSONParser.getJSONObject(url);    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {   cancel(true);   Log.v("", "failed");    }
    return null;
}
```

logcat

```
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704): ?{
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):     "artist_list": [
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):         {
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "id": "1",
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "artist_en": "MOTORHEAD",
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "artist_ar": "موتورهيد",
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "thumb_url": "http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/motorhead.jpg",
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "num_download": "2846"
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):         },
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):         {
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "id": "2",
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "artist_en": "WHITESNAKE",
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "artist_ar": "وايتسنيك",
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "thumb_url": "http://192.168.0.81:8080/content/whitesnake.jpg",
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):             "num_download": "1984"
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):         }
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704):     ]
09-25 16:04:31.869: V/(10704): }
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704): java.lang.InterruptedException
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1272)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:220)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:196)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerCancel(FutureTask.java:294)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:76)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at android.os.AsyncTask.cancel(AsyncTask.java:325)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at com.dwaik.jsonparser.ServerHit.doInBackground(ServerHit.java:36)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at com.dwaik.jsonparser.ServerHit.doInBackground(ServerHit.java:1)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-25 16:04:31.869: W/AsyncTask(10704):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: did you try to add `UTF-8` on load?

Comment: on load what? where to do that?

Comment: i already have it, ill post buildJSONString() implementaion

Comment: try to set ` httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` instead your header

Comment: didnt work :( I do set encoding in the buildJSONString() method, and the logcat prints the sting with no encoding problems, my problem is when I try to intantiate new jsonobject, JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject( s );

Comment: I posted one option it should work

Comment: where is the code where you call `cancel` on your asynctask ?

Comment: ill post the doinbackground() implementation and oncancel() is empty

Comment: it worked with my posted code after I changed json file encoding to ANSII instead of UTF-8 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String s = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Comes from [Android Java UTF-8 HttpClient Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480517/2122876)

You will have to import apache dependencies.

Comment: Oups Sorry, i faced a problem that seemed similar to yours. I thought it was the solution ... ;-)